# Mongodb Server Optimization for AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

Mongodb recommends the following settings:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-checklist-operations/

```
fs.file-max=98000
kernel.pid_max=64000
kernel.threads-max=64000
vm.max_map_count=128000
```

I'm wondering what the best settings for the greatest performance are for AWS t2.2xlarge?

Comment: Is there a reason to believe that the recommended settings aren't the best? In any case, this sounds more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Note that the documentation you liked to says: "the following values provide a good starting point".  That sounds a lot like YMMV